# How to prevent wrapping around of time when adding them in spreadsheet?

Tags: time, format, openoffice-calc

I have absolute values of time (as in stopwatch not date/time) in various cells and I would like to add them and keep them the same format (as an absolute value). I have formatted the cells using `hh:mm:ss` time format but when I add two values like:

```
22:34:00
 4:00:00
```

I see: `2:34:00` because of wrapping around the 24-hour time format, instead of `26:34:00`.

How can I do this with OO-Calc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution seemed to be to use the format, [HH]:MM:SS instead of HH:MM:SS.